# How to create a column based on different occurrences in rows over time?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a crisis variable based on the following criteria. An economic crisis begins with a contraction of GDP per capita (when the GDP growth is negative).
The crisis continues until GDP growth returns to or exceeds its level just before the crisis began. Can someone help?

Here is the expected output

[image]

Here is a reproducible code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(
  cntry = c(rep("Hungary", 15)),
  gdp = c(1, 1, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0.5, 1.9, 2, 0.5, 1, -1, 0, 0.5, 2),
  year = c(2000:2014)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible option to create your crisis variable:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(
  cntry = c(rep("Hungary", 15)),
  gdp = c(1, 1, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0.5, 1.9, 2, 0.5, 1, -1, 0, 0.5, 2),
  year = c(2000:2014)
)

data |>
  mutate(
    gdp_lag = lag(gdp, default = 0),
    crisis_begin = (gdp < 0) & !gdp_lag < 0,
    gdp_crisis_begin = if_else(crisis_begin, gdp_lag, NA),
    ix_crisis = cumsum(crisis_begin)
  ) |>
  fill(gdp_crisis_begin) |>
  mutate(
    row = row_number(),
    row_crisis_stop = first(row[!gdp < gdp_crisis_begin]),
    crisis = +(row < row_crisis_stop),
    .by = ix_crisis
  ) |>
  replace_na(list(crisis = 0)) |>
  select(cntry, gdp, year, crisis)
#>      cntry  gdp year crisis
#> 1  Hungary  1.0 2000      0
#> 2  Hungary  1.0 2001      0
#> 3  Hungary  2.0 2002      0
#> 4  Hungary -1.0 2003      1
#> 5  Hungary -1.0 2004      1
#> 6  Hungary  0.0 2005      1
#> 7  Hungary  0.5 2006      1
#> 8  Hungary  1.9 2007      1
#> 9  Hungary  2.0 2008      0
#> 10 Hungary  0.5 2009      0
#> 11 Hungary  1.0 2010      0
#> 12 Hungary -1.0 2011      1
#> 13 Hungary  0.0 2012      1
#> 14 Hungary  0.5 2013      1
#> 15 Hungary  2.0 2014      0
```

Comment: I tried to build a similiar solution, but it turned out to be tricky.

Comment: @MartinGal Yup. Would be interesting to know whether this could be achieved more easily and with less steps. (:

Comment: Thanks stefan, the year 2007 has a GDP growth of 1.9 which is lower than the pre-crisis level in 2002 which was 2.0. Therefore the crisis variable in 2007 should be 1 and not 0. Could you adapt this to the code please?

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Interpreted the end of the crisis as the period when the economy reaches the pre-crisis *level* of GDP. I just edited my code. Hope it now works.

Answer (score 2):

I would ofer this solution:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(sgn = sign(gdp-lag(gdp))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(sgn = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(crysis_stage = ifelse(sgn == -1 & lag(sgn) != -1, "Crysis begins", NA)) %>% 
  mutate(localmax = ifelse(crysis_stage == "Crysis begins", lag(gdp), NA)) %>% 
  fill(localmax, .direction="down") %>% 
  mutate(crysis_stage = coalesce(crysis_stage, ifelse(localmax<=gdp, "Crysis ends", NA))) %>% 
  mutate(crysis_stage = coalesce(crysis_stage, ifelse(!is.na(localmax), "Crysis continues", "Unknown"))) %>% 
  mutate(crysis_stage = ifelse(crysis_stage == "Crysis begins" & 
                                 (lag(crysis_stage) == "Crysis continues" | 
                                    lag(crysis_stage) =="Crysis begins"), 
                               "Crysis worsenes", 
                               crysis_stage)) 
    
    
     cntry  gdp year sgn     crysis_stage localmax
1  Hungary  1.0 2000   0          Unknown       NA
2  Hungary  1.0 2001   0          Unknown       NA
3  Hungary  2.0 2002   1          Unknown       NA
4  Hungary -1.0 2003  -1    Crysis begins        2
5  Hungary -1.0 2004   0 Crysis continues        2
6  Hungary  0.0 2005   1 Crysis continues        2
7  Hungary  0.5 2006   1 Crysis continues        2
8  Hungary  1.9 2007   1 Crysis continues        2
9  Hungary  2.0 2008   1      Crysis ends        2
10 Hungary  0.5 2009  -1    Crysis begins        2
11 Hungary  1.0 2010   1 Crysis continues        2
12 Hungary -1.0 2011  -1  Crysis worsenes        1
13 Hungary  0.0 2012   1 Crysis continues        1
14 Hungary  0.5 2013   1 Crysis continues        1
15 Hungary  2.0 2014   1      Crysis ends        1
```

The first 3 rows are unknown as we do not know on sure the local maximum of the period before the previous crysis.