# Identify peaks within a vector of -1s and 1s

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector which looks like this

```
1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
```

I need to get the groups of 1s and -1s, i.e.

`1, -1`, `1, 1, -1, -1, -1`, `1, -1`

with the eventual aim of getting the starting position of these groups and the end position, i.e.

starting positions: `1, 3, 8` and end positions: `3, 8, 10`

`rle()` doesn't quite get to what I want

```r
r <- rle(c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1))
which(rep(x = diff(sign(diff(c(-Inf, r$values, -Inf)))) == -2, times = r$lengths))
# [1] 1 3 4 8
```

So here, I don't want the `4`.

The vector I have given as an example may not cover all my bases. It is entirely plausible I have `0`s in the vector too. This would never intersect the `-1` and `1`, e.g.

`0 0 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1`

or

`1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 0 0`

or

`0 0 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 0 0`

or

`1 -1 0 0 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1`

could all be valid.

EDIT: The full code which I am trying to replace is

```r
xc <- paste(as.character(sign(diff(x))), collapse = "")
xc <- gsub("1", "+", gsub("-1", "-", xc))
xc <- gsub("0", zero, xc)
peakpat <- sprintf("[+]{%d,}[-]{%d,}", nups, ndowns)
rc <- gregexpr(peakpat, xc)[[1]]
if (rc[1] < 0) return(NULL)
x1 <- rc
x2 <- rc + attr(rc, "match.length")
attributes(x1) <- NULL
attributes(x2) <- NULL
```

(see `pracma::findpeaks()`). This code is *very* slow so I am trying to solve it using integers. So far I have

```r
    xc2 <- sign(diff(x))
    changepoints <- cumsum(abs(c(1, diff(xc2) != 0)))
    group_size <- tabulate(changepoints)
    lag <- c(NA, group_size[seq_len(length(group_size) - 1)])
    lead <- c(group_size[2:length(group_size)], NA)
    rc1 <- rep(0L, length(xc2))
    rc1[xc2 == 1 & rep(group_size >= nups, group_size) & rep(lead >= ndowns, group_size)] <- 1L
    rc1[xc2 == -1 & rep(group_size >= ndowns, group_size) & rep(lag >= nups, group_size)] <- -1L
    rc1_backup <- rc1
    rc1[rc1 == 0] <- -1
    x1 <- which(diff(c(0, rc1)) > 0)
    rc1 <- rc1_backup
    rc1[rc1 == 0] <- 1
    x2 <- which(diff(c(rc1, 0)) > 0) + 1
```

Which almost works...but not quite.

Comment: Is it possible you would have a leading -1 or a trailing 1? (e.g. `-1,0,1,1,-1,-1` or `1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1` ?

Comment: I believe it is only possible to have a leading `0` or `1` and a trailing `0` or `-1`.

Comment: What would be the expected output for a sequence with 0s?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why don't you want group `4:5`? It is also `c(1,-1)`.

Comment: And there is no position 10 in your sample vector

Comment: The "groups" are essentially the `1`s followed by `-1`s because this is considered to be a "peak". So I need to know where the peak starts (i.e. the first `1` and where it ends (i.e. the last `-1`. The `0`s come from the stipulation of the prior step - there must be at least `n` positive steps followed by at least `m` negative steps. So if the number of positive steps is `< n` or the number of negative steps is `< m` then we get a 0 for the whole group.

Comment: @asd-tm - the question defines the "end" of a sequence as the position starting the next one, not the final element, therefore the final 'end' point can be `length()+1`.  and they don't want 4:5 because the sequence of 1s starts at 3.

Comment: May my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287336/5043424) be useful? It deals with a more comlicated case and I calculated sgn (same as your vector of -1s, 0s and 1s)

Comment: `rle`  **will** give you what you want.  You just have to filter both on the `lengths` and the `values` output, thus identifying where a run of either "+1" or "-1" ends as well as begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, `rle()` gave me what I needed. I just needed the correct subsets.

```r
  rc <- rle(xc2)
  vals <- rc$values
  lens <- rc$lengths
  rc_len <- length(rc$lengths)
  lead <- c(vals[2:rc_len], NA)
  lead_lens <- c(lens[2:rc_len], NA)
  pos_peak_start <- which(vals == 1 & lens >= nups & lead == -1 & lead_lens >= ndowns)
  x1 <- (cumsum(c(0, lens)) + 1)[pos_peak_start]
  lag <- c(NA, vals[-rc_len])
  lag_lens <- c(NA, lens[-rc_len])
  pos_peak_end <- which(vals == -1 & lens >= ndowns & lag == 1 & lag_lens >= nups)
  x2 <- (cumsum(lens) + 1)[pos_peak_end]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
> x <- c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1)

> which(diff(c(0, x)) > 0)
[1] 1 3 8
```

Comment: This isn't a complete solution. It doesn't give me the finishing positions, `3, 8, 10`. Nor does it take group sizes `n` and `m` into account.

Comment: @nathaneastwood what if `x` ends with entry `1`? What is the expected output in that case?

Comment: @nathaneastwood The first is easy to incorporate just by changing it to `c(0, x, 2)` - your resulting vector will cover all start and/or end positions.  The second will require a more complex amendment.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I added an edit to my original question. Seemed I was getting somewhere with your solution but then realised it's possible to have `0`s in the vector too.

Comment: @nathaneastwood even with 0's this is the answer you are looking for. ie `c(which(diff(c(0, x)) > 0), length(x))` gives you all the start and end positions of all the groups.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way.

```
> (r <- which(diff(c(0L, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x) > 0L)) + 1L)) == 1L))
[1] 1 3 8
> c(r[-1], if (identical(tail(r, 1), len <- length(x))) NULL else len + 1L)
[1]  3  8 10
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(x)
c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using logical conditions:

```r
f <- function(x, n = 0){
  # Create the logical vector from conditions
  cond <- x == x[1] & c(0, x[-length(x)]) != x[1]
  
  #Start and ending indices
  start <- which(cond)
  end <- c(start[-1], length(x) + 1)
  
  #Subset based on size, n is the minimum number of elements (defaults to 0)
  wh <- which(tapply(x, cumsum(cond), FUN = length) > n)

  #Returns a list of start and end indices
  list(start = start[wh], end = end[wh])
}

#Starting with 1
f(x = c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1))
# $start
# [1] 1 3 8
# 
# $end
# [1]  3  8 10

#Starting with -1
f(x = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1))
# $start
# [1] 1 5 9
# 
# $end
# [1]  5  9 10

#Minimum 4 elements in the group
f(x <- c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1), n = 4)
# $start
# [1] 3
# 
# $end
# [1] 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to meet OP's changes:
Assumptions:

- The list may start with 1, never -1
- The list may end with -1, never 1
- The list may begin with, end with, or contain 0 but it will not appear in the middle of a 1,-1 pattern

```
# data:
testvec <- c(1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1)
testvec2 <- c(0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1)

cutup2 <- function(testvec, n = 1, m = 1) {
  # helper - do run length encoding
  testrle <- rle(testvec)
  # helper - define the break positions based on the criteria provided
  # note that the final break will be outside the length of the vector
  # as 'ends' are defined as the position _after_ the specific sequence.
  breaks = c(1, cumsum(testrle$lengths)+1)
  
  #define the data frame - number of rows should equal # of 1s in the RLE
  data.frame(
    start = breaks[c(testrle$values == 1, FALSE)],
    end = breaks[c(FALSE,c(testrle$values == -1))],
    num = testrle$lengths[testrle$values == 1],
    negnum = testrle$lengths[testrle$values == -1]
  ) |> dplyr::filter(num >= n & negnum >= m)
}
```

gives:

```
> cutup2(testvec,1,1)
  start end num negnum
1     1   3   1      1
2     3   8   2      3
3     8  10   1      1
> cutup2(testvec,2,2)
  start end num negnum
1     3   8   2      3
> cutup2(testvec2,1,1)
  start end num negnum
1     3   5   1      1
2     5  10   2      3
3    10  12   1      1
> cutup2(testvec2,2,2)
  start end num negnum
1     5  10   2      3
```

Explanation:
For "start" we are using the position of the first element in each set.
For "end" we are using the position of the first element of the NEXT set.
This means our breaks are all start positions, and can be listed by taking a vector of 1 and (the cumulative sum of the lengths +1) `c(1, cumsum(testrle$lengths)+1)`

The starts are selected based on the sequence of type `1` runs in the dataset and can never be the last one: `[c(testrle$values == 1, FALSE)]`

The ends are selected based on the sequence of type `-1` runs in the dataset, shifted one position towards the end (we want the start of the NEXT sequence) by the insertion of a `FALSE` `breaks[c(FALSE,c(testrle$values == -1))]`

For n and m (which I've called `num` and `negnum`) we just need the lengths of the rle for which the value is `1` or `-1` respectively.

I then filter by `n` and `m` - I've used `dplyr::filter()` but there are easy base R ways to do this if you prefer not to use the external package.

EDIT:
Tested with all provided examples:

```
testvecs <- list(c(1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1),
                 c(0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1),
                 c(1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0),
                 c(0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0),
                 c(1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1))

lapply(testvecs, cutup2, n = 1, m = 1)
lapply(testvecs, cutup2, n = 2, m = 2)
```

```
> lapply(testvecs, cutup2, n = 1, m = 1)
[[1]]
  start end num negnum
1     1   3   1      1
2     3   8   2      3
3     8  10   1      1

[[2]]
  start end num negnum
1     3   5   1      1
2     5  10   2      3
3    10  12   1      1

[[3]]
  start end num negnum
1     1   3   1      1
2     3   8   2      3
3     8  10   1      1

[[4]]
  start end num negnum
1     3   5   1      1
2     5  10   2      3
3    10  12   1      1

[[5]]
  start end num negnum
1     1   3   1      1
2     5  10   2      3
3    10  12   1      1

> lapply(testvecs, cutup2, n = 2, m = 2)
[[1]]
  start end num negnum
1     3   8   2      3

[[2]]
  start end num negnum
1     5  10   2      3

[[3]]
  start end num negnum
1     3   8   2      3

[[4]]
  start end num negnum
1     5  10   2      3

[[5]]
  start end num negnum
1     5  10   2      3
```

Comment: Sadly the assumptions do not hold true. I had to update my question to be more relevant to the true situation. Thanks for your efforts so far.

Comment: @nathaneastwood updated - please test if you are able.

Comment: For some reason I get `Error in data.frame(start = breaks[c(testrle$values == 1, FALSE)], end = breaks[c(FALSE,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 1520, 1519`

Comment: @nathaneastwood - I've just retested in a clean environment and it works for me - can you edit your OP to `dput()` post the dataset you're using that gives the problem?

Comment: @nathaneastwood note the change of function name - that error will come up if you use my original `cutup` function from the first draft.